# AppStore is missing after updating to iOS 10

Tags: ios

Just yesterday night I updated my iPhone with iOS 10.0.1 but after updating I have found that App Store is not there so I cannot download and install new apps . I realised I cannot even delete apps from phone

Comment: Did you try searching for it? (swipe down on any home screen)

Comment: Off course man , in the setting there is option of Facebook , twitter when I hit install button the settings window crashes and I am back on desktop

Comment: Do you have restrictions set up? Go to Settings -> General -> Restrictions and make sure restrictions for deleting and downloading apps are off.

Comment: Did you do a fresh, new install of iOS 10 or an update/restore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you don't have Restrictions set up: go to `Settings` -> `General` -> `Restrictions` and make sure restrictions for deleting and downloading apps are off. Then find the App Store app:

**On your home screen:** Just tap its [distinctive blue icon](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/Art/AppStore8_2x.png).

**Using Siri**:
Hold down your iPhone's home button and say, "Launch App Store".

**Using Spotlight Search**:
From your home screen, swipe your finger down from the center of the screen, then start typing "App Store".